# Custom Style For Lightning Toast

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system

Is there a way to customize the style (color, font-size, height) of lighting toast?
I'm trying with css but have no success.

Comment: Are you referring to [`force:showToast`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:showToast/documentation) or standard toast messages that you see in standard Lightning Experience?

Comment: It's force:showToast

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your comments, as you are using [`force:showToast`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:showToast/specification), you won't be able to custom style the component. The *Specification* tab on the documentation provides the attributes that you can utilize for the look and feel of the component which is mainly using `key`, `mode` and `type` attributes.

You will need to create a custom [toast message based on SLDS](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/toast/) for your use case where you can utilize custom CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Stylehooks to accomplish the styling of the standard Toast message.

You will be able to use the [documentation](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/toast/#Styling-Hooks-Overview) for reference.